# wxPython failing to install for Python 3.11.0

Tags: python, wxpython, python-3.11

When I try to install wxPython: `pip install wxpython`, the process runs for a long time and it causes the system to freeze. And I have to manually restart the machine holding down the power button.

I also tried to install the snapshot of the wxPython which also had the same errors as before.

**OS:** Windows 10 (21H2), 64-bit

**Pip Version:** 22.3

[Screen freezes at this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQkRZ.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: OS? Error messages? logs? How can anyone attempt an answer?

Comment: @Psionman I am so sorry for providing less information. I have added more details, if you need more details I am happy to provide it.

Comment: Sorry - I can't help with windows. I hope someone else can help

Answer (score 0):

Github Issue: https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/2296

WxPython Discussion: https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/wxpython-install-issue-on-macos-11-6-with-pyenv-and-python-3-11-0/36203

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).